# Android Confirmation dialog returning true or false

Tags: android, dialog, confirmation

It seems to be there is no easy way to get an Alert dialog to return a simple value.
This code **does not work** (the *answer* variable cannot be set from within the listener, in fact it does not even compile)

```js
public static boolean Confirm(Context context) {
    boolean answer;
    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    dialog.setTitle("Confirmation");
    dialog.setMessage("Choose Yes or No");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int buttonId) {
            answer = true;
        }
    });
    dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int buttonId) {
            answer = false;
        }
    });
    dialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
    dialog.show();
    return answer;
}
```

NOTE: It is important that the method is self contained, i.e., it does not depend on variables or constructs external to it. Just call it and get your answer, true or false.

So, what to do? This simple wish of returning **true** or **false** seems to be much more complicated than it deserves.

Also, the setButton method has the form:

```js
dialog.setButton(int buttonId, String buttonText, Message msg)
```

But it is not clear how to use it, where is the meesage sent to, to whom, which handler is used?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I was going to say that I am very pleased with myself because I found a simple answer, all by  myself!
But the truth is that although I find a way to return a value (which I show below). **It is of no use**.

The real problem is I wanted a synchronous Dialog, a dialog that waits for the user to answer before resuming your code after `dialog.show()`.
**There is no such beast in Android**. All dialogs are asynchronous, so `dialog.show()` only posts the dialog in some queue (I think) and continues. Thus you don't get your answer in time.

For all its worth (nothing) below you'll find how to set a value inside the method that builds the dialog. Maybe there are other uses for this technique, not related to the dialog lifecycle.

To give some related info, I'll say that if you replace

```js
boolean answer;
```

with

```js
final boolean answer;
```

it is possible to access the variable from within the listener, but it is not possible to assign it a new value, since it was declared as **final**.

Here comes the trick.
Define the variable as:

```js
final boolean[] answer = new boolean[1];
```

Some of you already see why this will work. The final variable here is not the single element of the boolean array, is the array itself.
So now you can assign the array element [0] as you wish.

```js
dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int buttonId) {
        answer[0] = true;
    }
});
. . .
return answer[0];
```

And finally you can return it from your method.

Comment: You ever find a better solution?

Comment: @Lion789 As I stated, this is not really a solution and I explainded why with the current Android OS there cannot be a soultion. So, in short, I did not find a better solution. According to Android, you should put your code inside the onClick() listener for the dialog. That's the only way to execute it after you close the dialog.

Comment: iLomambo Did you try the one up top with calling Runnable

Comment: I have moved since to other projects, so I have not tried it. But if you understand my answer it is pretty obvious how it's going to behave. Because of the **asynchronous** character of Android, the moment you call `show()` the dialog is displayed and the code **moves on**, it does not wait for the user click on `OK`

Comment: right but if there is nothing else in the code but for example onClick(dialog(proca(), procb()) the screen will only change after a selection regardless of async because in procA I tell it what to do and that wont get executed unless it is told to run in the dialog

Answer (score 18):

i have post similiar problem in this forum, but finally i get my answer.
my problem in that post is how to create separate confirm dialog class who can acces by other class or activity, so with that confirm dialog class we don't need to write long coding.

here's my answer.

First you must create DialogHandler.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import src.app.R;

public class DialogHandler {
    public Runnable ans_true = null;
    public Runnable ans_false = null;

    // Dialog. --------------------------------------------------------------

    public boolean Confirm(Activity act, String Title, String ConfirmText,
            String CancelBtn, String OkBtn, Runnable aProcedure, Runnable bProcedure) {
        ans_true = aProcedure;
        ans_false= bProcedure;
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(act).create();
        dialog.setTitle(Title);
        dialog.setMessage(ConfirmText);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, OkBtn,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int buttonId) {
                         ans_true.run();
                    }
                });
        dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, CancelBtn,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int buttonId) {
                        ans_false.run();
                    }
                });
        dialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
        dialog.show();
        return true;
    }
}
```

And this is example to call it in another class

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(myclick);
    }

    public final Button.OnClickListener myclick = new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            doclick();
        }
    };

    public void doclick() {
        DialogHandler appdialog = new DialogHandler();
        appdialog.Confirm(this, "Message title", "Message content",
                "Cancel", "OK", aproc(), bproc());
    }

    public Runnable aproc(){
        return new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.d("Test", "This from A proc");
            }
          };
    }

    public Runnable bproc(){
        return new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.d("Test", "This from B proc");
            }
          };
    }


}
```

Comment: @Lion789 See my response to your comment in my own answer. The real test here is: put some code in the `onClick()` method **after** invoking `doClick()` to check the user response to the `DialogHandler` dialog and see if that code execution waits for the dialog to close. I think it will not.

Comment: I like your approach and it is running . I have checked it.

Comment: @Roro Great job. It works. This should be the accepted answer

Comment: @AsepRoro Nice logic..Works nicely. This one indeed needs to be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

What you can do is create a Listener for your Alert Dialog that listens to AlertDialogs action using an Interface.

Create an Interface.

```
public class MyInterface {

    DialogReturn dialogReturn;

    public interface DialogReturn {

        void onDialogCompleted(boolean answer);
    }

    public void setListener(DialogReturn dialogReturn) {
        this.dialogReturn = dialogReturn;
    }

    public DialogReturn getListener() {
        return dialogReturn;

    }
}
```

Now, in your class just implement the Interface that you created using `implements MyInterface.DialogReturn`

then you can set the Listener and get it working as show below,

```
public class Main extends Activity implements MyInterface.DialogReturn{

    MyInterface myInterface;
    MyInterface.DialogReturn dialogReturn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                ....
        myInterface = new MyInterface();
        myInterface.setListener(this);
    }


   public void Confirm(Context context) {
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        dialog.setTitle("Confirmation");
        dialog.setMessage("Choose Yes or No");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int buttonId) {
                myInterface.getListener().onDialogCompleted(true);
            }
        });
        dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int buttonId) {
                myInterface.getListener().onDialogCompleted(false);
            }
        });
        dialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
        dialog.show();
         }


@Override
    public void onDialogCompleted(boolean answer) {
        Toast.makeText(Main.this, answer+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(answer)
            // do something
            else
            // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I am assuming your suggestion works. But, what a complicated way to achieve a simple thing ! Don't you think?

Comment: Ya true, but this is not that much complicated if we understand it once and get it working.

Comment: @ilomambo <unsolicitedEditorial>Welcome to Android! Welcome to Java for that matter.</unsolicitedEditorial>

Answer (score 1):

I find that using [jDeferred](https://github.com/jdeferred/jdeferred) helps in cases where you want to wait for input.

It is essentially equivalent to using an interface, but instead you create done and fail handlers. Just an alternative to consider:

```
new ConfirmationDialog(mContext)
        .showConfirmation("Are you sure?", "Yes", "No")
        .done(new DoneCallback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onDone(Void aVoid) {
                ....
            }
        })
        .fail(new FailCallback<Void>() {

            @Override
            public void onFail(Void aVoid) {
                ...
            }
        });
```

Implementation:

```
public class ConfirmationDialog {


    private final Context mContext;
    private final DeferredObject<Void, Void, Void> mDeferred = new DeferredObject<Void, Void, Void>();

    public ConfirmationDialog(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public Promise<Void, Void, Void> showConfirmation(String message, String positiveButton, String negativeButton) {
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).create();
        dialog.setTitle("Alert");
        dialog.setMessage(message);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, positiveButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int buttonId) {
                mDeferred.resolve(null);
            }
        });
        dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, negativeButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int buttonId) {
                mDeferred.reject(null);
            }
        });
        dialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
        dialog.show();
        return mDeferred.promise();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Andriod, it is not a good idea to block the running thread by waiting for the user to say 'yes' or 'no'.

In order to ask for a confirmation, you can define a method that receives an AsynTask. The method executes that task if the user press the confirm button.

For example:

```
    //this method displays a confirm dialog. If 'yes' answer, runs 'yesTask', 
    //if 'no' answer, runs 'noTask'
    //notice than 'yesTask' and 'noTask' are AysncTask
    //'noTask' can be null, example: if you want to cancel when 'no answer'

    public static void confirm(Activity act, String title, String confirmText,
                       String noButtonText, String yesButtonText,
                       final AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> yesTask,
                       final AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> noTask) {

    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(act).create();
    dialog.setTitle(title);
    dialog.setMessage(confirmText);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, yesButtonText,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int buttonId) {
                yesTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
            }
        });
    dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, noButtonText,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int buttonId) {
                if(noTask!=null) {
                    noTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                }

            }
        });
    dialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
    dialog.show();
}
```

You can call it from your activity with:

```
 YourTask yourTask =  new YourTask( ... );
 confirm( YourActivity.this, 
         "Confirm", 
         "Are you sure?", 
         "Cancel", 
         "Continue", 
         yourTask,
         null);
```

`YourTask` class must extend `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 0):

Declare a field 'answer' in your activity and set a value to it. Fields of a class are visible to inner classes, so you can do that.

Comment: Yes.. I did not mention it, but I need the method to be independent of the class it is defined in. Cannot use a class variable. I will update the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling to use a blocking confirm dialog and I finally did it using a BlockingQueue :

```
public static class BlockingConfirmDialog{

    private Activity context;

    BlockingQueue<Boolean> blockingQueue;

    public BlockingConfirmDialog(Activity activity) {
        super();
        this.context = activity;
        blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Boolean>(1);
    }

    public boolean confirm(final String title, final String message){

        context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                        blockingQueue.add(true);
                    }
                 })
                 .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        blockingQueue.add(false);
                    }
                })
                 .show();
            }
        });

        try {
            return blockingQueue.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all of the solutions and the easier and cleanest is by far the first  solution with the Runnable, in my opinion. It supports the dialog on the Cancel button listener, the OnBAckPressed() and the onOptionsItemSelected().

The code as described though calls the ans_false.run(); when clicking the BUTTON_POSITIVE and the ans_true.run(); when clicking the BUTTON_NEGATIVE.

Here is the code I used to fix that problem:

```
public class MyDialogs {

// private constructor
public Runnable answerTrue = null;
public Runnable answerFalse = null;

// Dialog. --------------------------------------------------------------

public boolean confirm(Activity act, String Title, String ConfirmText,
                       String noBtn, String yesBtn, Runnable yesProc, Runnable noProc) {
    answerTrue = yesProc;
    answerFalse= noProc;
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);
    alert.setTitle(Title);
    alert.setMessage(ConfirmText);
    alert.setCancelable(false);
    alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_positive, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            answerTrue.run();
        }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.button_negative, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            answerFalse.run();
        }
    });
    alert.show().getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).requestFocus();
    return true;
}
```

}