# Why this won't notify the Thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, notify

I always wondered how most applications create confirmation dialogs, I can get mine working. I know you can't block the UI Thread so I have something like this:

```
private synchronized boolean createDialogConfirm() {
        if(DEBUG) Log.i("Dialog", "createDialogConfirm()");
        // Creo un nuevo Thread que crea el cuadro de dialogo TODO: no funciona la confirmacion, nunca llega al return
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Creo el dialogo con los dos botones
                AlertDialog.Builder confirm = new AlertDialog.Builder(LogicAnalizerView.this);
                confirm.setTitle("Guardar");
                confirm.setMessage("El archivo existe, sobreescribir ?");
                if(DEBUG) Log.i("Dialog", "createDialogConfirm() -> Created");

                // Boton Si
                confirm.setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {    
                      state = true;
                      synchronized(this) { this.notifyAll(); };     // Despierta el Thread
                  }
                });

                // Boton No
                confirm.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                      state = false;
                      synchronized(this) { this.notifyAll(); };
                      dialog.dismiss();   
                  }
                });
                confirm.show();
            }
        });

        if(DEBUG) Log.i("Dialog", "createDialogConfirm() - Thread created");
        try {
            synchronized(this) { wait(); }; // Queda esperando (no retorna nada) hasta que se llame a notify() en algun boton
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return state;
    }
```

So I use it on this way inside a Thread (not UI Thread):

```
if(createDialogConfirm()){ ... }
```

I know it's an ugly way but I dont know other way if you have anyone I would love to hear it. The problem is that if I call notifyAll() or notify() whitout synchronized(this){} I get Force Close on my app, but if I use it it simply never returns, it seems no never notify() the Thread.
The idea is to return a true or false from the Thread but only when the user have pressed some button.

Comment: Why you make things so complex? ""I know you can't block the UI Thread""  but you are actually doing your most of work (creating a dialogue) is in UI thread, which off course the main thread. 

What problem you are facing in making a simple dialogue(Without so complexity)?

Comment: If you read the question you will see I don't want to simply create a dialog, I want to wait in a dialog for the user input but of course whitout blocking the UI thread

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Interface` to get notified/return some value from your AlertDialog. Check my answer [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10764182/726863).

Comment: The Dialog is created I can see it, but the value is never returned. show() also creates the Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem comes from the fact that you are synchronizing on `this`, which is a different object when you call `notifyAll` than when you call `wait`, since when you call `notifyAll` you are inside a `new Runnable(...)` object. Try to synchronize on a neutral object. Furthermore you whould guard the `wait` with a boolean condition to ensure against timing races or spurious wakeups:

```
private synchronized boolean createDialogConfirm() {

        final Object signal = new Object(); // !
        final boolean[] shouldWait = new boolean[] { true };

        if(DEBUG) Log.i("Dialog", "createDialogConfirm()");
        // Creo un nuevo Thread que crea el cuadro de dialogo TODO: no funciona la confirmacion, nunca llega al return
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Creo el dialogo con los dos botones
                AlertDialog.Builder confirm = new AlertDialog.Builder(LogicAnalizerView.this);
                confirm.setTitle("Guardar");
                confirm.setMessage("El archivo existe, sobreescribir ?");
                if(DEBUG) Log.i("Dialog", "createDialogConfirm() -> Created");

                // Boton Si
                confirm.setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {    
                      state = true;
                      synchronized(signal) { shouldWait[0] = false; signal.notifyAll(); }     
                  }
                });

                // Boton No
                confirm.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                      state = false;
                      synchronized(signal) { shouldWait[0] = false; signal.notifyAll(); }
                      dialog.dismiss();   
                  }
                });
                confirm.show();
            }
        });

        if(DEBUG) Log.i("Dialog", "createDialogConfirm() - Thread created");
        try {
            while(shouldWait[0]) {
               synchronized(signal) { signal.wait(); }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return state;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you I will try that, do you know of another way much simpler because I still have to create a new thread to use it right?

Comment: @Andres: Yes you still need the thread. Unfortunately I don't really know much about android in particular, I just answered based on my java threading knowledge, so I can't really suggest any better way...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but it didn't worked :/ I have called it inside a thread new Thread(new Runnable(){ if(createDialogConfirm()){ ... } }).start(); but when I click in any button I get: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()". And I also tried to put the new Thread() inside the method to have a cleaner way to call it but I can't return the value on this way.