# View Confirmation recharge billing Dialog when send SMS

Tags: android, sms, android-billing

In the following Code to send SMS using SMS Manager:

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();                                                      
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null,message, null, null);
```

In the below dialog that i recieve it when the device android version 4.3 or 4.4.
how can detect status if click Send or cancel?

[image]

Comment: isnt it automatically sending the message if you click send?

Comment: yes it's not automatically , but how can i detect if click send to be know send SMS or cancel to dimis this dialog

Comment: Is this dialog coded by you? or is it coming automatically?

Comment: its coming automatically

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763986/android-confirmation-dialog-returning-true-or-false is this of any help?

Comment: have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You will find that you can't detect status if click Send or Cancel as long as you read the corresponding source code.

"The default behavior for sending a message to a premium SMS short code (or suspected premium SMS number) is to ask the user for confirmation. Enable the user to set a default policy ("remember this choice" checkbox) to always/never allow the app to send SMS to premium short codes in the future. The policy can be changed by the Settings app in the app info screen."
[See here for details](https://gitorious.org/primerunner/frameworks_opt_telephony/commit/4658a1a8c23111d5cc89feb040ce547a7b65dfb0)

The dialog is defined in 
src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/SMSDispatcher.java

```
 /**
* Post an alert when SMS needs confirmation due to excessive usage.
* @param tracker an SmsTracker for the current message.
*/
protected void handleReachSentLimit(SmsTracker tracker) {
    if (denyIfQueueLimitReached(tracker)) {
        return; // queue limit reached; error was returned to caller
    }
    CharSequence appLabel = getAppLabel(tracker.mAppInfo.packageName);
    Resources r = Resources.getSystem();
    Spanned messageText = Html.fromHtml(r.getString(R.string.sms_control_message, appLabel));
    ConfirmDialogListener listener = new ConfirmDialogListener(tracker);
    AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
           .setTitle(R.string.sms_control_title)
           .setIcon(R.drawable.stat_sys_warning)
           .setMessage(messageText)
           .setPositiveButton(r.getString(R.string.sms_control_yes), listener)
           .setNegativeButton(r.getString(R.string.sms_control_no), listener)
           .setOnCancelListener(listener)
           .create();
   d.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
   d.show();
  }
```

And the Callbacks of negative and positive button:

```
 /**
* Dialog listener for SMS confirmation dialog.
*/
private final class ConfirmDialogListener
implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener, DialogInterface.OnCancelListener,
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    private final SmsTracker mTracker;
    private Button mPositiveButton;
    private Button mNegativeButton;
    private boolean mRememberChoice; // default is unchecked
    ConfirmDialogListener(SmsTracker tracker) {
       mTracker = tracker;
    }
    void setPositiveButton(Button button) {
       mPositiveButton = button;
    }
    void setNegativeButton(Button button) {
      mNegativeButton = button;
    }
@Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
// Always set the SMS permission so that Settings will show a permission setting
// for the app (it won't be shown until after the app tries to send to a short code).
      int newSmsPermission = SmsUsageMonitor.PREMIUM_SMS_PERMISSION_ASK_USER;
      if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
         Log.d(TAG, "CONFIRM sending SMS");
// XXX this is lossy- apps can have more than one signature
         EventLog.writeEvent(EventLogTags.SMS_SENT_BY_USER,
         mTracker.mAppInfo.signatures[0].toCharsString());
         sendMessage(obtainMessage(EVENT_SEND_CONFIRMED_SMS, mTracker));
         if (mRememberChoice) {
             newSmsPermission = SmsUsageMonitor.PREMIUM_SMS_PERMISSION_ALWAYS_ALLOW;
         }
         } else if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {
             Log.d(TAG, "DENY sending SMS");
// XXX this is lossy- apps can have more than one signature
        EventLog.writeEvent(EventLogTags.SMS_DENIED_BY_USER,
            mTracker.mAppInfo.signatures[0].toCharsString());
            sendMessage(obtainMessage(EVENT_STOP_SENDING, mTracker));
        if (mRememberChoice) {
            newSmsPermission = SmsUsageMonitor.PREMIUM_SMS_PERMISSION_NEVER_ALLOW;
        }
    }
       setPremiumSmsPermission(mTracker.mAppInfo.packageName, newSmsPermission);
}
```

When you click the Send or Cancel button on the dialog, it will send a message to its handler in its thread. But it seems that there is no way for you to capturing the click event.