# Handling Android's SMS sending Limit Popup?

Tags: android, smsmanager

Hi I am developing an android application to send SMS in Bulk. I am using the code  [proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8579311/1798737).
 The problem is I am getting a popup and I want to listen to SMSDispatcher's EVENT_SEND_LIMIT_REACHED_CONFIRMATION and if the user has allowed or denied the permission.

Answer (score 0):

The system in question is the [SmsUsageMonitor](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/3f4415e31c8c407e0397511fdc2d5906361295fa/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/SmsUsageMonitor.java). The usage monitor does not have any public API and does not raise any events when the user makes a selection in the dialog.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982319/view-confirmation-recharge-billing-dialog-when-send-sms) for a possible duplicate.