# Show “SMS Services that cost you money” dialog before sending automated SMS

Tags: java, android, smsmanager, android-sms

The core logic of my app is to detect a particular keyword from an upcoming SMS and then if it matches a certain condition it will send an automated SMS with a specified recipient, the app has a `Switch` view if activated it will listen to all incoming SMS.

I have done all of the necessary permission requests like.

```
SEND_SMS
RECEIVE_SMS
READ_SMS
```

The problem is every time the app matches that certain conditions and it is about to send an SMS it shows a dialog with.

> “SMS Services that cost you money” with positive and negative button

I am definitely sure that the dialog is not a permission but more of like a system default.

And it breaks the logic of the app, since it should automatically send an SMS when that particular keyword is matched resulting into bad UX, i think this only shows a dialog if the API version is lower than API 23 (i could be wrong).

Now is there any way to request the user to grant the app access to always send an SMS before the app is about to send an automated SMS?

Comment: here :
[View Confirmation recharge billing Dialog when send SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982319/view-confirmation-recharge-billing-dialog-when-send-sms)

Comment: @AliReza Thank you! I find it useful.